# How to Time TCP/IP Transaction

Tags: c#, performance, datetime, time, tcp

I currently have 2 client server models. In both, I'm passing a large amount of data from the server to the client. I would like to time how long it takes before the data gets serialized on the server side til when all the data gets received by the client; ultimately, I would like to see how much faster 1 model is than the other.

My question: What is the best way to do this?

My gripe is that this would require starting a timer on the server side and having a stop time on the client side. While I could take the respective start and stop times of both machines, there are several issues with this approach e.g. the system times of both machines aren't synchronized, time zone differences, etc...

I'm currently looking at individual metrics of 1 model and comparing it to the other which works but doesn't quite capture the overall transaction time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the client respond back when it has received everything. That way the server knows when that is and can perform the measurement all by itself. You'll measure one additional round trip but that will be about the same in all measurements.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: some time ago I made a Java class (and a Javascript library) as a proof of concept and starting point for people who want to synchronize machines within a network and within not perfect but decent precision: http://currentmillis.com/api/CurrentTime.java (that pinpoints the system time of a client machine relatively to the (time) server and tries to take network latency out of the question, with a formula like localTime = serverTime + (localResponseTime - localRequestTime) / 2. But the point is it can be extended with a more complex, customizable algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a halfway decent approach:

Start a timer on the client, and call the server.  The first thing the server does is start a timer.  At the end of its processing, it stops the timer, calculates the amount of time it spent processing, and returns that time back to the client.

The client can then subtract this time from the overall time to determine transport overhead (serialization, network transmit time, etc..), and unless your network is relatively busy the return response of a single time value should not be a significant amount of that time.  If you're being pedantic, you can perform a test which does the same thing but only sends a single time value, and returns the time value, then you divide it by two to figure out what the result of one way would be, then subtract that from the time as well.

Of course network communication is not an exact science, and it can take different times from one invocation to the next, so you'll probably want to perform a number of tests, throwing away the outliers.

So, as an example:

Start timer: 0s.
Make call:
Call received: Start new timer: 0s
Finished processing: 50ms
return 50ms
original receiver gets result, timer says 120ms.

Subtract 50ms from 120ms, and you now have 70ms with some fudge area for the return time.

Comment: Ah I see, so the fudge area comes under the assumption that timer value of client -> server is gonna be about the same as server -> client. That's pretty much close enough but I guess I've just come to accept that there's no easy way of obtaining an absolute transaction time.

Comment: @nivla12345 - well, for similar parameters/return types they should be similar, yes.  In a perfect world.. of course network timings can vary from call to call.. so you have to get averages.